# eval() performance - one big or many small?

Tags: php, performance, eval

If I have a large html page I retrieve from a database, and it has multiple small PHP tags within it that need to be eval()ed. Is it better performance wise to just eval() the whole page, or to break it up and eval() just the small snippets individually?

Comment: Can you give an example of why you need to use eval() - perhaps show us some of your source ?

Comment: How would it be possible to `eval` them one by one? Can you guarantee that none of the blocks will depend on context created by those preceding it?

Comment: I'd be better to not use `eval` at all.  You could write the file from the DB into a temp file, `include` it, then remove the temp file.  Or, just keep the file in the file system (and not the DB) in the first place.

Comment: @Rocket: Eval / Include is pretty much the same. Even I like your suggestion that code does not normally belong in the database, it's a users choice where to store code, in a SQL database, or in a file based data-base.

Comment: @Rocket- Is the temp file technique really better than a straight eval()? Please elaborate, never considered it.

Comment: @Yarin: I'm not really sure if it's better, I just always thought `eval` was slow and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: @hakre: Pretty sure `include` and `eval` are different in how they operate.

Comment: Both `eval` and `include` use the same PHP internal parsing mechanism (it's furthermore called `ZEND_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL` in `Zend/main.c`). The performance and security attributions are mostly hypothetical. -- But when paying customers demand it, I would even just set up a stream wrapper to allow for `include("sql:table=xyz;id=123.php");` to the same effect.

Comment: @mario- Very interesting, but now I have to ask- if they are based on the same mechanism, why do the stream wrapper technique- that's another one I've never heard of- can you elaborate?

Comment: @Yarin: The streamwrapper (was close to suggest it as well), would allow you to use `include` similar to the encapsulation with `execute_page` in my answer below. Probably with `include` the interface is even more descriptive what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll spend more time processing/splitting than you would with the single eval(). PHP's already quite efficient at loading/parsing/executing code from a file, so let it do what it's good at, rather than second guessing the system and adding extra unnecessary overhead.

Of course, if you're really gung-ho for it, you can try both methods and do some benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer your question. However, one suggestion I can give is that first of all, you should encapsulate the problem, for example into a function of it's own:

```
/**
 * @param $page
 * @return void
 */
function execute_page($page)
{
    # ... - fetch code from store based on $page parameter and execute it.
}
```

After you've done that, you can later on change not only where you store the page, but also how you execute it (chunks, at once).

The rest of you application only needs to call that function and you don't need to care much for the rest of your code about it any longer.

You can then test which method / variant is faster.